# why my if condition does not work (if (n>2))?

Tags: java, filereader

```
//this code is to compare two files and delet stop list word from file algorithm    
FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Sara\\Desktop\\IRP\\Information Retrieval\\Algorithm.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
FileReader readerStopList = new FileReader("C:/Users/Sara/Desktop/IRP/stopwords2.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReaderStopList = new BufferedReader(readerStopList);
String word, stopword, newWord = "";
while ((word = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    for (int k = 0; k < word.split(" ").length; k++) {
        int count = 0;
        newWord = word.split(" ")[k];
        int n = newWord.length();
        if (n > 2) { //this statment to skip words of length 2
            while ((stopword = bufferedReaderStopList.readLine()) != null) {

                for (int j = 0; j < stopword.split(" ").length; j++) {

                    if (newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(stopword.split(" ")[j])) {
                        count++;

                    }
                }
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                System.out.println(newWord);

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please format your post.

Comment: You just ruined the formatting - fix it.

Comment: Can you try printing what `newWord` holds? Just do a `System.out.println(newWord);`  before  grabbing the length.

Comment: Also please post what value `stopwords2.txt`  has? We can't tell anything if there is no indication of the values inside the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume n > 2 is true once, then you read all the lines from your bufferedReaderStopList until you reach the EOF. This means that whenever n > 2 is true again the inner loop over bufferedReaderStopList will never be entered since readLine() always returns null from now on.

For starters your code needs to be structured better, add the content of bufferedReaderStopList into an array first at least. Also avoid doing split on the word string several times. Do it once and use the resulting array instead.

Comment: stopwords.txt is a file that contains stoplist words (eg. that, the, a ...)

Comment: newWord is a word in the algorithm.txt that I want to compare it with all words in stopwords.txt if it is in stopwords file then i must skip it and do not print if